# Cannot update Decimal (30,18) value in Sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update a value in sql server 2012 with Entity framework for an MVC 5 application. The field is a `Decimal(30,18)`. I start by setting the value 120 which is stored successfully. Then when I try to update the value by setting 121 I get the following exception on `SaveChanges()`

> System.InvalidOperationException: The given value of type Decimal 
>       from the data source cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified 
>       target column. ---> System.ArgumentException: Parameter value 
>       '121.000000000000000000' is out of range.

I have tried playing around with decimal precision but this makes no sense to me. As far as I know 30,18 means I can have 30 digits of which the 18 can be the decimal points so the above exception shouldn't be thrown.

I add some more code in order to help with fixing this. I am using automapper but even if i do just the following i get the same error.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)))
{
     Product.Categories.FirstOrDefault().Instrument_Entry_Cost = 3.4M;
     this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
     scope.Complete();
}
```

What i also noticed is that if i go to SQL Server and manually set the value 3,4 to the specific column it accepts it. Only if i try and update the value through entity framework this issue occurs

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you share the UPDATE query as well?

Comment: I am not using an sql update query. I am updating the entity by using the entity framework. I retreive the db record, change the decimal value and then I just save the changes using the context (dbcontext.SaveChanges())

Comment: Updated code and issue with more info @Andres2142

Comment: Since it is an InvalidOperationException and not a SQL exception maybe the model is not up do date with the SQL server tables?

Comment: @Magnus The  model is set as a nullable decimal in code and I updated the edmx. I am using database first approach.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that to change field type Decimal to float

Comment: I cannot do that as I need the decimal precision set to (30,18). I need to keep the precision and update the entity with greater decimals